# Number Stored as Text when Writing Query to a Worksheet

Tags: mysql, ruby, excel, rubygems

I am creating a report using the following gems:

```
require "mysql2"
require "watir"
require "io/console"
require "writeexcel"
```

After I query a database with `mysql2` and convert the query into a multidimensional array like so:

```
Mysql2::Client.default_query_options.merge!(:as => :array)

mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "01.02.03.405", :username => "user", :password => "pass123", :database => "db")

report = mysql.query("SELECT ... ASC;")

arr = []
report.each {|row| arr << row}
```

and then finally write the data to an Excel spreadsheet like so:

```
workbook = WriteExcel.new("File.xls")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheetname = "Report")

header = ["Column A Title", ... , "Column N Title"]

worksheet.write_row("A1", header)
worksheet.write_col("A2", arr)

workbook.close
```

when I open the file in the latest edition of Excel for OSX (Office 365) I get the following error for **every** cell containing mostly numerals:

[image: Excel error.]

This report has a target audience that may become distracted with such an error.

I have attempted all the `.set_num_format` enumerable methods found in the documentation for `writeexcel` [here](http://writeexcel.web.fc2.com/en/doc_en.html#set_num_format).

How can I create a report with columns that contain special characters and numerals, such as currency, with `write excel?`

Should I look into utilizing another gem entirely?

Comment: You're adding an array to a cell. Do you mean to add just one number?

Comment: @tadman `worksheet.write_row("X7", arrayOne)` is a method inherited from the `writeexcel` gem that writes the contents of the multidimensional array `arrayOne` to the worksheet `worksheet`, beginning with the top left-most cell `X7`.  More on this [here](http://writeexcel.web.fc2.com/en/doc_en.html#write_row).

Comment: Right, but you're using `write_col` in your example.

Comment: @tadman I'm using *both* and they both work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the format after you create the worksheet.

```
format01 = workbook.add_format  
format01.set_num_format('#,##0.00')
```

then write the column with the format.

```
worksheet.write_col("A2", arr, format01)
```

Since I'm not a Ruby user, this is just a S.W.A.G.

Comment: Your answer works and prevents the error from occurring, but **only** if the value(s) within `arr` are `float`.  I will need to make sure that every column that contains currency is `.to_f` but this works very nicely.  Thank you.